# After updating Postgres, my Rails server logs are black and white (no color coded SQL operations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

How do I fix my `rails s` log to have color again? I haven't uninstalled any gems or anything--the only change that was recently made was that I upgraded Postgres through Homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The real reason this was happening is because my codebase had

```rb
config.colorize_logging = false
```

in an initializer file. Make sure this value is not set to `false` anywhere! It defaults to `true` (ref [ruby docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-colorize-logging))